# How do I identify my own parts in an MEF catalogue?

Tags: .net, prism, mef

Following the article Create composite modular UI application in WPF using MEF and PRISM, I have the WPF application as instructed, and my view injected into a region on the main window works fine. However, for the module project that exports MEF Parts, I have set the output directory to a parts repository directory somewhere. When I build the solution, my `ModuleA.dll` gets placed in that directory, but with all it's dependencies.

I use a `DirectoryCatalog` on that parts repo directory, and it contains 26 parts, only 1 of which is mine. I would like to extract a list of parts that are mine from that directory, not using raw reflection myself, e.g. not by examining assemblies and building an `AssemblyCatalog`. Is there any way I can call `Parts` on the directory, and examine the exports to see which is mine? If I browse the catalogue, I can see my Part, but I can't see any properties I can examine to do this grammatically.

Comment: what defines an assembly as "yours"?

Comment: The one I wrote, Robert; the one that contains my 1 out of 26 Parts in the catalogue.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to load things from a single specific assembly, that kinda goes against the whole point of MEF... if that's what you want, just reference that assembly directly.  If you want to do things the MEF way, the app shouldn't be concerned with what's in the catalog - it should just "import" the interface it needs and let the framework figure out which part satisfy this interface.  Assuming you have defined a custom interface for your part, MEF will only find the one implementation of it in your 1 assembly and won't find anything in the other 25 assemblies.